# How to define and use environment variables within strings in dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Our directory contains `dags` and `plugins` subdirectories. We have been trying for an hour to make this `Dockerfile` work :

```
...
# Set AIRFLOW_HOME
ENV AIRFLOW_HOME="/root/airflow"

# Create airflow directory to populate it with dags
RUN mkdir -vp $AIRFLOW_HOME
## Import dags
ADD dags '${AIRFLOW_HOME}/dags'
ADD plugins '${AIRFLOW_HOME}/plugins'
...
```

No matter what we tried, the `dags` and `plugins` subdirectories would just not be created under the specified path. Until we did this :

```
ADD dags ${AIRFLOW_HOME}'/dags'
ADD plugins ${AIRFLOW_HOME}'/plugins'
```

I.E. Removed the `${AIRFLOW_HOME}` from under the string brackets... Why is this behaving this way? Could you provide an explanation of what we're doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main error is that the ADD source folder **must** be relative to docker file context path, so you cannot use absolute paths:

The second error is that you cannot pass environment variables to some docker commands, so you have to use `ARG`.

Here an example:

```
ARG AIRFLOW_HOME /root/airflow
WORKDIR ${AIRFLOW_HOME}

## Import dags

ADD dags {{dags target folder under WORKDIR}}
ADD plugins {{plugins target folder under WORKDIR}}
```

ANd remember to place `dags` and `plugins` source folder under the docker context path.

Comment: Oh so I have to define a `WORKDIR` and use it. Thnx !

Comment: Since the container's filesystem layout is fixed at build time, I wouldn't even use an `ARG` here.  Set `WORKDIR /root/airflow`, and then use relative paths on the right-hand side of `ADD` (or, better, `COPY`): `COPY dags ./dags`.